# Angular CLI creates new project with empty index.html

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using the Angular CLI to create a new project using the following command

```
ng new AngularProject
```

This command creates a folder with my newly created project. I now go to the /src folder to see all the files. But when I open index.html, nothing happens? I just see an empty page.
I am aware that you can use `ng build` to create the /dist folder with the build files or `ng serve` to run the project with a webserver. But I just want to use all the files from the /src folder without changing the structure of this folder.

How can I get my index.html in the /src folder to work without building or serving?

Comment: You can't. Angular is used to create web apps. Web apps are served from a web server. Not from the file system. The index.html in the src folder is a source file, meant to be transformed by the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer ... you can't. An Angular application cannot be executed in development mode by opening the index.html file.

The `ng build` command transpiles the code from TypeScript to JavaScript, bundles the code, and updates the index.html file with the defined bundles.

These files can be deployed to a Web server, which will then serve the index.html file appropriately.